# I applied for passport 8 months ago and still no passport, anyone have any idea what I can do to get my passport quicker?

Tags: passports, us-citizens, application-status

I applied for a passport back on 04/06/21, was given an Application Locator Number, and status at one point said they received my application on 04/20/21,and it is now 12/27/21, and still no passport and the online status went from "In Process" with a application locator number, and now for the last 3 weeks the status shows as "Not Available", and I have received nothing about needing more documentation or if there are any problems.  Any one else still waiting on their new passport for over 8 months? And I paid for expedited service.  Does anyone know if there is something, other than checking the online status of my passport or by calling the 1-877-487-2778 number, as I get no answers as to why the 8 month wait, when all government updates are saying the processing times are 8 to 11 weeks.  Please help with what I can do to get my passport and soon.

Comment: Is this your first US passport, or a renewal? If it's a renewal, have you changed your nane, or has your previous passport been long expired?

Comment: @CSM Even if that is the case there’s no explanation why a passport application should take 8 months.

Comment: I know several people whose passports delayed this year, several. The maximum was 15 weeks. 8 months is ridiculous and you should file a complaint ASAP.

Comment: It is my first,  and none of the submitted information needs to be updated, and no name change.... How do I file a complaint?

Comment: Try also contacting your Congressional representatives.

Comment: I know that due to COVID passport office is slammed and there are tons of delays, but 8 months is excessive. Second "call your congressman" suggestion, they usually have a way to speed things up with government agencies.

Comment: This might not apply to you, but I have heard that the US does not give you a passports if you owe back taxes or alimony.